# How to use the new value of a variable in PHP?

Tags: php

Why does $validSave always contains FALSE even I click the btnEdit?

Here's the code:

```
$validSave = false;

if(isset($_POST['btnSearch'])){
   if(isset($_POST['btnEdit']){
     $validSave = true;
   }
}

if(isset($_POST['btnSave']){
     if($validSave){
         ... //Does not go here after I press the btnEdit
     }
     else{
        echo "Unable to save"; //It always goes here
     }
}
```

Comment: put `if(isset($_POST['btnEdit']){ $validSave = true; }` outside `if(isset($_POST['btnSearch']))`

Comment: It *always* starts out being `false`, and the only time it will be set to `true` is if you POST both `btnSearch` *and* `btnEdit` at the same time. The variable does not keep its state between separate requests!

Comment: What would be the solution to it? I'm not very familiar to php.

Comment: That depends on what exactly you want this to do and how you envision the flow to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$validSave` always contains FALSE because `if(isset($_POST['btnSearch']))` and `if(isset($_POST['btnEdit'])` are false.if one condition is true and one condition is false then state will not change of `$validSave` if you have two button `if(isset($_POST['btnSearch']))` and `if(isset($_POST['btnEdit'])` try to use like this

```
if(isset($_POST['btnSearch']) || isset($_POST['btnEdit'])){
  $validSave = true;
}
```

or if you have one button and one field you need to try like that

```
if(isset($_POST['your button name'])){
   $otherField=$_POST['btnSearch'];
    $validSave = true;
}
```